# Web Service won't connect to database

Tags: mysql, web-services, glassfish-3

I have a java web service which i deploy on glassfish 3. I set up a MySQL DB connection pool to my database which is located on the same server as the glassfish.

If I ping the DB from admin console it will be successful, but when I try to run my web service and test it, which has the location of the database set as well as it's username and password it will fail to connect. Here's the error i get when testing:

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:326) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:102) at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:137) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97) at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:297) ... 28 more Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:189) at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:130) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89) at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140) at $Proxy255.verifyUserAccount(Unknown Source) ... 33 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at ManagersBD.UserManager.verifyUserAccount(UserManager.java:153) at WebService.SocialServerWS.VerifyUserAccount(SocialServerWS.java:148) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.glassfish.webservices.InstanceResolverImpl$1.invoke(InstanceResolverImpl.java:137) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:95) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*doRun(Fiber.java:588) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:112) at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:138) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*_doRun(Fiber.java:629) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*doRun(Fiber.java:588) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:112) at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:195) at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:127) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.*_doRun(Fiber.java:629) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573) at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470) at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:295) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:519) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:288) at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143) at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:149) ... 26 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this. The problem wasn't anythin I was doing. The server admins forgot to install JDBC driver on the server so it wouldn't connect.

Comment: I didn't do anything, I only asked the server admins to install the JDBC driver that's all that was the problem.

Comment: how do I ask the JDBC to install. please run me the steps.